# Ramification index and residue class degree under completion

Tags: number-theory

I've got a problem in proving something written at page 111 of the book "Algebraic Number Theory" by A. Fröhlich and M. J. Taylor.

This is the setting. Let $\mathfrak{o}$ be a Dedekind domain with field of fraction $K$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $\mathfrak{o}$ and $L$ a finite separable extension of $K$. Denote by $\mathfrak{o}_{L}$ the integral closure of $\mathfrak{o}$ in $L$ and fix a prime ideal $\mathfrak{P}$ of $\mathfrak{o}_{L}$ above $\mathfrak{p}$, i.e. such that $\mathfrak{o}\cap \mathfrak{P}=\mathfrak{p}$. Let $v$ be the (discrete) valuation on $L$ associated with $\mathfrak{P}$ (discrete valuations are always understood to be surjective onto $\mathbb{Z}$ in this context) and $\vert . \vert_{\mathfrak{P}}$ an absolute value on $L$ associated with $\mathfrak{P}$, i.e. $\vert x\vert_{\mathfrak{P}} =\lambda ^{v(x)}$, for a fixed $0<\lambda<1$. The *ramification index* of $\mathfrak{P}$ in $L/K$ is defined as $$e:=v(\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{o}_{L}),$$ so that $$\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{o}_{L}=\mathfrak{P}^{e}\mathfrak{a},$$
for $\mathfrak{a}$ an ideal of $\mathfrak{o}_{L}$ coprime with $\mathfrak{P}$. The *residue class degree* of $\mathfrak{P}$ in $L/K$ is defined as $$f:=[\mathfrak{o}_{L}/\mathfrak{P}: \mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}].$$

Now, the authors say

> We claim that both $e$ and $f$ are invariant under completion with respect to $\vert . \vert_{\mathfrak{P}}$. Indeed, writing $\bar{}$ for the closure in this completion and using the fact that $\bar{\mathfrak{P}}$ is the only prime ideal of $\bar{\mathfrak{o}_{L}}$, by the Corollary to Theorem 11, $\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{o}_{L}=\mathfrak{P}^{e}\mathfrak{a}$ gives $\bar{\mathfrak{p}}\cdot\bar{\mathfrak{o}_{L}}=\bar{\mathfrak{P}}^{e}$ which proves the result for the ramification indices. The result for residue class extension degrees follows from the isomorphism of $\mathfrak{o}_{L}-$modules $$\mathfrak{o}_{L}/\mathfrak{p}\simeq \bar{\mathfrak{o}}_{L}/\bar{\mathfrak{P}}$$
>   shown in Theorem 11.

Theorem 11 is the following:

**Theorem 11**. Let $\mathfrak{o}$ be a Dedekind domain, which is not a field, and $K$ its field of fractions. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $\mathfrak{o}$, $v$ the associated valuation of $K$ and $\vert .\vert$ the corresponding discrete absolute value, such that $\vert a\vert=\lambda^{v(a)}$ for some $0<\lambda<1$ and every $a\in K$. Let also $(\bar{K},\ \parallel . \parallel)$ be the completion of $(K,\ \vert .\vert)$ and $j\colon K\hookrightarrow \bar{K}$ the embedding.

- There is a unique valuation $\hat{v}$ of $\bar{K}$ with the property that $\parallel\alpha \parallel=\lambda^{\hat{v}(\alpha)}$ for every $\alpha\in\bar{K}$. Also $\hat{v}$ restricts to $v$ on $K$ under the map $j$.
- Let $\hat{\mathfrak{o}}$ denote the (discrete) valuation ring of $\hat{v}$ and $\hat{\mathfrak{p}}$ its unique maximal ideal. For $Y\subseteq \bar{K}$, let $\bar{Y}$ denote the closure of $Y$ in $\bar{K}$ with respect to the topology induced by $\parallel . \parallel$. Then, for all $r\in\mathbb{Z}$, $\bar{j(\mathfrak{p}^{r})}=\hat{\mathfrak{p}}^{r}$ and in particular $\bar{j(\mathfrak{o})}=\hat{\mathfrak{o}}$.
- The map $j\colon \mathfrak{o}\rightarrow \hat{\mathfrak{o}}$ induces isomorphisms $\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}^{r}\simeq \hat{\mathfrak{o}}/\hat{\mathfrak{p}}^{r}$.

The Corollary to Theorem 11 is the following

**Corollary** Let $I_{\mathfrak{o}}$ and $I_{\hat{\mathfrak{o}}}$ denote the abelian groups of fractional ideals of $\mathfrak{o}$ and of $\hat{\mathfrak{o}}$ respectively. The homomorphism sending a fractional ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ of $\mathfrak{o}$ to the fractional ideal $\mathfrak{a}\hat{\mathfrak{o}}$ of $\hat{\mathfrak{o}}$ is completely determined by $\mathfrak{p}\hat{\mathfrak{o}}=\hat{\mathfrak{p}}$ and $\mathfrak{q}\hat{\mathfrak{o}}=\hat{\mathfrak{o}}$, if $\mathfrak{q}$ is any prime ideal of $\mathfrak{o}$ other than $\mathfrak{p}$.

Now, when all is said and done, the point is: can someone explain plainly how to derive the authors' claims starting from Theorem 11 and its Corollary?

Up to now I've been able to prove that $$(\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{o}_{L})\hat{\mathfrak{o}}_{L}=\bar{\mathfrak{P}}^{e},$$
but why should the lhs be equal to $\bar{\mathfrak{p}}\cdot\bar{\mathfrak{o}_{L}}$ (which, I guess, should be the ideal of $\bar{\mathfrak{o}_{L}}$ generated by $\hat{\mathfrak{p}}$, right?) ?

Also about the residue class degree: I understand that $\mathfrak{o}_{L}/\mathfrak{p}\simeq \bar{\mathfrak{o}}_{L}/\bar{\mathfrak{P}}$, but how can I say that $\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}\simeq \bar{\mathfrak{o}}/\bar{\mathfrak{p}}$ (if this is true!) in order to conclude that $f=[\bar{\mathfrak{o}_{L}}/\bar{\mathfrak{P}}: \bar{\mathfrak{o}}/\bar{\mathfrak{p}}]$ ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its too complicated

Comment: Many of these properties become easier to see in the general context of completing finitely generated modules with respect to ideals of noetherian rings. The basic properties of completion in this context require a bit more work than one might expect, but looking at the completion chapter in Atiyah MacDonald should give you all the general results.